# Get Highcharts graph to skip a date if it doesn't exists in the X-Axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that shows specific values across a date range. The issue I'm having is that sometimes a waste type will skip a month. Below is the array that I'm using, and you can see from the "Recycling" part of the array it jumps from `May 14` to `Jul 14`.

```
Array
(
    [Recycling] => Array
        (
            [May 14] => 7040
            [Jul 14] => 3920
            [Aug 14] => 14560
            [Sep 14] => 15120
            [Oct 14] => 12420
            [Nov 14] => 13440
            [Dec 14] => 13720
            [Jan 15] => 3920
        )

    [Disposal (Landfill)] => Array
        (
            [May 14] => 3800
            [Jun 14] => 7820
            [Jul 14] => 8100
            [Aug 14] => 5520
        )

    [Energy Recovery] => Array
        (
            [May 14] => 340
            [Jun 14] => 8500
            [Jul 14] => 6640
            [Aug 14] => 2860
            [Sep 14] => 7360
            [Oct 14] => 5380
            [Nov 14] => 8380
            [Dec 14] => 5440
            [Jan 15] => 1600
        )

)
```

The X-Axis of the graph displays a range of dates between the lowest date in the data array through to the current date as you can see here:

[image]

As you can see, the Recycling line (green) still plots a point in `Jun 14` even though it doesn't have any data for that month. Really it should skip that month and go to `Jul 14`.

How can I get the graph to behave properly?

This is the code I have:

```
        init.push(function () {
            $('#wh2Chart').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    height:250,
                    animation: {
                        duration: 1500,
                        easing: 'easeOutBounce'
                    },
                },
                title: {
                    text: '',
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [{% for key,value in seldates %}'{{value}}',{% endfor %}]
                    //categories: [{% for key,value in newWHM %}{% for key, v in value %}'{{key}}',{% endfor %}{% endfor %}]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: '(tonnes)'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: 't'
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    floating: false,
                },
                series: [
                {% for key,value in newWHM %}
                    {% if key == 'Prevention' %}
                        {
                            name: '{{key}}',
                            data: [{% for key, v in value %}{{v|tonne}},{% endfor %}],
                            color: '#008729'
                        },
                    {% elseif key == 'Reuse' %}
                        {
                            name: '{{key}}',
                            data: [{% for key, v in value %}{{v|tonne}},{% endfor %}],
                            color: '#86b400'
                        },
                    {% elseif key == 'Recycling' %}
                        {
                            name: '{{key}}',
                            data: [{% for key, v in value %}{{v|tonne}},{% endfor %}],
                            color: '#3CB400'
                        },
                    {% elseif key == 'Minimisation' %}
                        {
                            name: '{{key}}',
                            data: [{% for key, v in value %}{{v|tonne}},{% endfor %}],
                            color: '#915b14'
                        },
                    {% elseif key == 'Energy Recovery' %}
                        {
                            name: '{{key}}',
                            data: [{% for key, v in value %}{{v|tonne}},{% endfor %}],
                            color: '#da7300'
                        },
                    {% elseif key == 'Disposal (Landfill)' %}
                        {
                            name: '{{key}}',
                            data: [{% for key, v in value %}{{v|tonne}},{% endfor %}],
                            color: '#ca000e'
                        },
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}

                ]
            });
        });
```

Also, for information, the data is coming from a Symfony2 system and is rendered inside a Twig file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use categores, so all points are pritned from first value. When you have a strings, highcharts doens't recongise your start point. So you have to solutions

- use [datetime](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) type of xAxis and convert your x values to timestamps
- manipulate [pointStart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart) on the particular serie